# Handling errors in jQuery.getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

jQuery's [getScript](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript) function doesn't seem to support an error callback function. I can't use the global ajax error handling code here, a local error function would be ideal.

Documentation that the callback gets data/textStatus seems incorrect - the callback gets neither.

Any suggestions on how I detect that a call to getScript failed (server not available, for instance)?

EDIT: Just looked at source, and it seems like the callback is only invoked on success, with data always set to null and textStatus not defined (since it's a success-only callback, I presume). The documentation is very incorrect for this function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but..

You could declare a variable inside the scripts you load and check for it after you've loaded a script (assuming that the complete-function still fires):

script_test.js:

```
var script_test = true;
```

And then:

```
$.getScript("script_test.js", function ()
{
    if (typeof script_test !== undefined) alert("script has been loaded!");
});
```

Or you could just try and see if whatever is in your script, actually exists--functions, variables, objects, etc.

A more generic way to do this would be adding a self-executing function inside the scripts you want to load, and make them execute a function in your "main" script:

main_script.js:

```
function scriptLoaded(scriptName)
{
    alert(scriptName + " loaded!");
}

$.getScript("script_test.js");
```

script_test.js:

```
(function ()
{
    scriptLoaded("script_test.js");
})();
```

Comment: yea, this is what I'm doing currently but like you said, it's a bit of a hack. Btw, the code should read <code> if ( typeof script_test !== "undefined" ) ... </code>

Comment: Aye, it's a hack. Did you consider my 2nd example? And.. I don't believe you need the typeof operator.

Comment: Thanks for that second suggestion. Also, unless I'm really going nuts, you will need the typeof if the var isn't defined anywhere already. Try running this function below in your script (make no mention of foo before). You'll notice an error in the js console: function test(){ if (foo === undefined) alert("Yay!"); }

Answer (score 33):

As of jQuery 1.5 you can append a .fail to your call to getScript.

```
$.getScript('foo.js', function(){
    //script loaded and parsed
}).fail(function(){
    if(arguments[0].readyState==0){
        //script failed to load
    }else{
        //script loaded but failed to parse
        alert(arguments[2].toString());
    }
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/#handling-errors

Comment: The `fail` callback doesn't seem to work if the script is a cross-domain url (neither does the `always` callback or the global `ajaxError` handler.

Comment: The `fail` callback works with cross-domain URLs in jQuery 2.0+

Answer (score 17):

For cross domain script tags, the success event fires but the error event does not; no matter what syntax you use. You can try this approach:

1. Create an error handler and set it to fire after few seconds using `handle = window.setTimeout`
2. Inside your success callback function, cancel the timeout using `window.clearTimeout(handle)`

Sample code:

```
var timeoutId; // timeout id is a global variable
timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
    alert("Error");
}, 5000);
$.getScript("http://other-domain.com/script.js", function(){
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```

Comment: At first this seems to be quite an ugly solution, but it's the only one that actually works with adblockers. So thanks for that!

Comment: I'd love to know if this ever got addressed in a newer version of jQuery.  I am noticing this and I am using jQuery 1.8.3.  However, I am noticing that neither callback gets called.  The jsonp service I am using returns a 400 header in this case.  I can't find anyway to deal with it on the client when I use jQuery.

Comment: @Anthony : Jquery 2.x supports error handlers now (1.x still doesn't)

Answer (score 8):

The global JQuery Ajax-ErrorHandler will work!

Prior to the $.getScript-Call setup the Error Handler to cach the error.

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
    alert('error in: ' + settings.url + ' \n'+'error:\n' + exception );
});
```

As described in the JQuery manual: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/.

Answer (score 4):

jquery.ajax has a alternative way to handle error

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://www.example.com/script_test.js',
        dataType: "script",
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('error ', errorThrown);
        },
        success:function(){
            console.log('success');
        }
    });
```

Comment: elegant solution :) . Preferred than the above even if previous solution is reported in the official documention https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ in section Handling Errors.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use jQuery 2.0+ the `$.getScript` seem to be the wrong choice, because it does not provide any error handling capabilities while making cross-domain requests. None of those: `fail`, `complete`, `error`, `statusCode` will work. I've checked it with jQuery 1.11.2
Solution with `setTimeout` will be too slow if you have to load fallback script when the first will fail.
In this case `script.onerror` callback seem to be the cleanest way.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
document.head.appendChild(script);
script.onload = function () {
    // loaded
};
script.onerror = function () {
    // failed
};
script.src = 'https://example.com/main.js';
```

In combination with `$.Deferrred` provides reliable way to build complex loaders.

```
var libLoaded = $.Deferred();
var script = document.createElement('script');
document.head.appendChild(script);
script.onload = libLoaded.resolve;
script.onerror = function () {
    // load fallback script, no error handling
    $.getScript('/fallbackLib.js')
        .done(libLoaded.resolve)
};
script.src = 'https://example.com/lib.js';

$.when(libLoaded).then(
    // fanally I can use my lib safly
);
```

Comment: Initially I only thought that I had needed your first code block but we had discovered an edge case where the async operations needed to occur synchronously so the second block helped to achieve that. Awesome suggestion. Thank you.